# How can i delete all list items by one click

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete all the items in my listView by clicking on ButtonIcon .
I am using flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoxYU.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody can help you unless you share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setState( () {
  myItems.clear();
});
```

or

```
 myItems.clear();
setState( () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list view is built around a list called ‘myItems’ say, then you need to clear the list and then force a rebuild.

```
setState( () {
  myItems = [];
});
```